# MVC 3 file upload and model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a form upload that works but I would like to pass model information for my database to save the file with a different name of course.

Here is my Razor view:

```
@model CertispecWeb.Models.Container

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "AddDocuments";
}

<h2>AddDocuments</h2>

@Model.ContainerNo

@using (Html.BeginForm("Uploadfile", "Containers", FormMethod.Post, 
            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type='file' name='file' id='file' />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Uploadfile(Container containers, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
     if (file.ContentLength > 0)
     {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"),
                       containers.ContainerNo);
        file.SaveAs(path);
     }

     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The model information is not passed through to the controller. I have read that I might need to update the model, how would I do this ?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411563/asp-net-mvc3-razor-file-upload-gives-zero-as-file-count for a related problem

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Your form doesn't contain any input tag other than the file so in your controller action you cannot expect to get anything else than the uploaded file (that's all that's being sent to the server). One way to achieve this would be to include a hidden tag containing the id of the model which will allow you to retrieve it from your datastore inside the controller action you are posting to (use this if the user is not supposed to modify the model but simply attach a file):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Uploadfile", "Containers", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

and then in your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Uploadfile(int id, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    Containers containers = Repository.GetContainers(id);
    ...
}
```

On the other hand if you wanted to allow the user to modify this model then you will need to include the proper input fields for each field of your model that you want to be sent to the server:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Uploadfile", "Containers", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Prop1)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Prop2)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Prop3)
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

and then you will have the default model binder reconstruct this model from the request:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Uploadfile(Container containers, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am getting `file` as `null` and `Request.Files.Count` is 0 too, would there be any difference if the `form` is an `AjaxForm` and there are `routeValues` as well?

Answer (score 8):

Solved

Model

```
public class Book
{
public string Title {get;set;}
public string Author {get;set;}
}
```

Controller

```
public class BookController : Controller
{
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Create(Book model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload)
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
}
```

And View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Book", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{      
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m)

     <input type="file" name="fileUpload[0]" /><br />      
     <input type="file" name="fileUpload[1]" /><br />      
     <input type="file" name="fileUpload[2]" /><br />      

     <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="SubmitMultiply" value="Upload" />
}
```

Note title of parameter from controller action must match with name of input elements
`IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload` -> `name="fileUpload[0]"`

`fileUpload` must match

Comment: This solution is the only solution I found for multiple files. Thanks for sharing your code.

Answer (score 6):

If you won't always have images posting to your action, you can do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Uploadfile(Container container, HttpPostedFileBase file) 
{
    //do container stuff

    if (Request.Files != null)
    {
        foreach (string requestFile in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[requestFile]; 
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string directory = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/");
                if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
                }
                string path = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For multiple files; note the newer "**multiple**" attribute for input:

Form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileImport","Import",FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <label for="files">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple="true" id="files" />
    <input type="submit"  />
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileImport(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1st download jquery.form.js file from below url

http://plugins.jquery.com/form/

Write below code in cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "frmTemplateUpload" }))
{
    <div id="uploadTemplate">

        <input type="text" value="Asif" id="txtname" name="txtName" />


        <div id="dvAddTemplate">
            Add Template
            <br />
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" tabindex="2" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <input type="button" id="btnAttachFileCancel" tabindex="3" value="Cancel" />
        </div>

        <div id="TemplateTree" style="overflow-x: auto;"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="progressBarDiv" style="display: none;">
        <img id="loading-image" src="~/Images/progress-loader.gif" />
    </div>

}


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        alert('sample');
        var status = $('#status');
        $('#frmTemplateUpload').ajaxForm({
            beforeSend: function () {
                if ($("#file").val() != "") {
                    //$("#uploadTemplate").hide();
                    $("#btnAction").hide();
                    $("#progressBarDiv").show();
                    //progress_run_id = setInterval(progress, 300);
                }
                status.empty();
            },
            success: function () {
                showTemplateManager();
            },
            complete: function (xhr) {
                if ($("#file").val() != "") {
                    var millisecondsToWait = 500;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        //clearInterval(progress_run_id);
                        $("#uploadTemplate").show();
                        $("#btnAction").show();
                        $("#progressBarDiv").hide();
                    }, millisecondsToWait);
                }
                status.html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

    });


</script>
```

Action method :-

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            return View();
        }

 public void Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string txtname )
        {

            try
            {
                string attachmentFilePath = file.FileName;
                string fileName = attachmentFilePath.Substring(attachmentFilePath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

           }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```