# Uploading files with MVC 3

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-mvc-3, upload

I'm growing thin learving mvc3. I have the following code in my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Accreditation(Accreditation accreditation)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var fileUpload = Request.Files[0];
            var uploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads");

            using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, accreditation.PressCard.ToString()), FileMode.Create))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[fileUpload.InputStream.Length];
                fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            context.Accreditations.Add(accreditation);
            context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }


           ViewBag.PossibleNationalities = context.Nationalities;
            ViewBag.PossibleNchis = context.Nchis;
            ViewBag.PossibleMedia = context.Media;
            ViewBag.PossibleEmploymentStatus = context.EmploymentStatus;
            return View(accreditation);



    }
}
```

Here's the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Accreditation", "Home", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" },    FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
.............
.............

<div class="editor-field">
       <input type="file" name="PressCard" id="PressCard" data-val-required="Press card is required" data-val="true"/>
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PressCard)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Passport)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
       <input type="file" name="Passport" id="Passport" data-val-required="ID/Passport is required" data-val="true"/>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Passport)
    </div>
```

.......
........

When I try to upload, i get the following error message:

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Any one out there with a pointer to  the right direction?

---

sorry for delay. Here's the new code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Accreditation(Accreditation accreditation, HttpPostedFileBase Passport)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var uploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads");

            using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, accreditation.PressCard.ToString()), FileMode.Create))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[Passport.InputStream.Length];
                Passport.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            context.Accreditations.Add(accreditation);
            context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }


           ViewBag.PossibleNationalities = context.Nationalities;
            ViewBag.PossibleNchis = context.Nchis;
            ViewBag.PossibleMedia = context.Media;
            ViewBag.PossibleEmploymentStatus = context.EmploymentStatus;
            return View(accreditation);



    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Are really uploading data? I'd suggest you use this way. Create a parameter of type HttpPostedFileBase with the **same name** as the input field and test for its content length property.

## Don't forget to use the same name for the parameter and for the input tag.

Checking this link will the fastest way for you to move on.

[MVC 3 file upload and model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784225/mvc-3-file-upload-and-model-binding/4784292#4784292)

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback, means alot

i changed the action to read 
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Accreditation(Accreditation accreditation, HttpPostedFileBase Passport)
        {

}
New error Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Edgar Ochieng, please, post the new code in the answer so we can have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Get your posted file directly in action:

Here is discussion on SO: [MVC 3 file upload and model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784225/mvc-3-file-upload-and-model-binding)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Accreditation(Accreditation accreditation, HttpPostedFileBase Passport)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback, means alot

i changed the action to read 
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Accreditation(Accreditation accreditation, HttpPostedFileBase Passport)
        {

}
New error Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

`var fileUpload = Request.Files[0];` is the line where you have your exception, isn't it? You should expect the file to be stored in the property of class `Accreditation`, not in `Request.Files`.

So you need properties `PressCard` and `Passport` in `Accreditation`, both of type `HttpPostedFileBase`, and then use these properties in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback, means alot

i changed the action to read 
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Accreditation(Accreditation accreditation, HttpPostedFileBase Passport)
        {

}
New error Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.