# Uploading an image to the database using asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, asp.net-web-api

I have created a form to upload details about an advertisement and I need to upload an image with it.At the end of all my efforts still I see the image column as NULL in the database.HOw do I fix this issue?please note that I am a beginner.

Code for the view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Advertisement", FormMethod.Post,  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Advertisement</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OwnerID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OwnerID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OwnerID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category,(SelectList)ViewBag.CategoryList)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category)
    </div>

    **<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="file" id="MyFile" runat="server" />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image)
    </div>**

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>


    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Post"  />
    </p>
</fieldset>


 }
```

And the form looks like below
[image]

In my model i am using "byte[]" type for the Image property.At the sql database I am using Varbinary(max) type for image column.

code in database table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Advertisements] (
[ID]          INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Title]       NVARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
[OwnerID]     INT             NOT NULL,
[Date]        DATETIME        NOT NULL,
[Category]    NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
[Image]       VARBINARY (MAX) NULL,
[Description] NVARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Advertisements] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)


  );
```

Controller action

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "ID")]Models.Advertisement advertisement) //submits the result
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var db = new AdvertisementDataContext();
        db.Advertisements.Add(advertisement);
        db.SaveChanges(); //saved to the database

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return Create(); // if there was an error show the form again

}
```

Comment: Code please so we can see that portion of what's going on

Comment: Adam I have added the code

Comment: whats the byte array look like inside of your Advertisement object when you hit this method? Is it null or is there data there? Also you should be doing: using (var db = new AdvertisementDataContext()){ code here }

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpPostedFileBase to send your file to the controller as a parameter ala:
[MVC 3 file upload and model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784225/mvc-3-file-upload-and-model-binding)

then you'll need to convert that parameter to a byte array and save it like you are doing (sorry, on phone will try to edit shortly)