# Bind value to model in Asp.Net MVC Application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view

In my model i have a HttpPostedFileBase property as File. In the view I have a textbox "A" and a button "B". I also have a hidden input type="file" id ="file "on my page. On B click i trigger the #file.click in my javascript. The selected file should then bind to the model property and the file name should be displayed on the textbox. I am unable to do this. Any help? I hope the question is clear, if not please tell me so that i can elaborate further.

Any help?

Edit 1:

Model:

```
public class FileUploadModel
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
        public string FileName {get;set;}
    }
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Browse").click(function () {

            $("#fileIputType").trigger('click');

           //now the file select dialog box opens up
          // The user selects a file
          // The file should get associated with the model property in this view
          // the textbox should be assigned the filename 

        });
    });
</script>


    @Html.TextBox("fileTextBox", Model.FileName, new { id = "fileTextBox" })

        <input type="button" id="Browse" name="Browse" value="Browse" />

        <input type="file" id="fileInputType" style="visibility:hidden"/> 

        @Html.Hidden("ModelType", Model.GetType())

  //How can i bind the selected file to the model property ( public HttpPostedFileBase File )
```

Comment: It would help if you show some code.

Comment: @WannaCSharp i have added some code...if it helps :)

Comment: In your script, you have $("#fileIputType") but in your html you have id="fileInputType"

Comment: @charlieparker so? its an id...thats how we access it, isnt it?

Comment: I think its displayed to the textbox but you can't see it because its hidden??

Comment: the textbox is not hidden, the file select is hidden, and the more important question is why not it is getting binded

Comment: kewal, my point was that you have a typo when you access it.  You're missing the letter "n" in $("#fileIputType").  Iput != Input.  If you retyped your code here it's probably not actually causing a problem, but if you copied and pasted it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `File` to the name property of your file input

```
    <input type="file" name="File" id="fileInputType" style="visibility:hidden"/>
```

And this would bind to `HttpPostedFileBase file` parameter in your action method when you submit the form.

Edit:

Remeber to set your form's `entype` to `multipart/form-data`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data" })
```

Comment: Did you set the form's enctype to multipart/form-data? Check my edit

Comment: Do you have `FileUploadModel` as your parameter or just `HttpPostedFileBase` ?

Comment: Try accepting `HttpPostedFileBase` as your parameter if it will work.

Comment: hmm..will try...thanks for your patience...btw gotta run an important errand...will get back to you with the results

Comment: hi...can you look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855836/bind-value-to-model-in-asp-net-mvc-application-part-2

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the `input type='file'` elements `value` property in javascript programatically.

Why dont you show the File name as a label text? Have a `FileName` property in your model(viewmodel) class

```
@model MyViewModel

{

<label>@Model.FileName</label>
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your code

```
public class FileUploadModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    public string FileName {get;set;}
}
```

In view

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
```

In Controller

```
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        model.File.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    }
```

Comment: i dont want to set the input type='file' elements value property in javascript. I just want to display in the textbox the name of the file . And i want to bind the file selected by input type = "file" to the model property

Comment: @kewal, for have File as FileStream property in model and also FileName property for TextBox and use both

Comment: i am unable to bind and i get null when i debug it in the controller

Comment: @kewal, check how to bind `File` element with model

Comment: i tried...unable to find anything concrete...can you point in the right direction maybe

Comment: @kewal check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304617/html-helper-for-input-type-file) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784225/mvc-3-file-upload-and-model-binding)

Comment: checking now...will get back to you

Comment: hi...can you look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855836/bind-value-to-model-in-asp-net-mvc-application-part-2