# How to create Property to hold FileUpload Files

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have class of EmployeeDocumentsTable

```
public class EmployeeDocumentsTable
{
   public HttpPostedFileBase EmployeeDocumentFileName { get; set; }

   // Other properties
}
```

in my view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmployeeDocumentFileName, new { type = "file" })
```

The problem is when I post the form using submit button the property EmployeeDocumentFileName is null.

Comment: Your form should have multi part attribute see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125127/asp-net-mvc-4-c-sharp-httppostedfilebase-how-do-i-store-file

Answer (score 0):

1) Does your form include enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute ?

2) See this answer [MVC 3 file upload and model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784225/mvc-3-file-upload-and-model-binding)